How to tell if a UIViewController's view is visible after it presents another UIViewController with UIModalPresentationOverFullScreen style?
I have ViewControllerA, and it presents ViewControllerB with UIModalPresentationOverFullScreen style because ViewControllerB has a clear background color and I want to see part of ViewControllerA's view after that.
In this case, viewWillDisappear and viewDidDisappear of ViewControllerA are not called.
Then, ViewControllerB will push ViewControllerC, which has an opaque background color, onto its navigation stack. After this, ViewControllerA's view becomes fully invisible.
So my question is: is there any way I can tell if ViewControllerA's view is somewhat visible(after presenting ViewControllerB) or totally invisible(after pushing ViewControllerC)?
